# The lab have a constant electric field and a constant magnetic field, what is the electric and magnetic field inside a conductor and far from it

Tags: electromagnetism, work

The following is an old question from an exam in a Physics $2$ course
I am taking, I have tried to solve the question and after I thought
I got the answer I looked at the solution and saw it isn't correct.

The solution explains what the answer is, but doesn't really explains
the facts used.

> In the lab frame there is an electric field $E=E_{y}$ and a magnetic
>   field $B_{z}=\beta E$.
>
> We place a cube made of a conducting material, point $a$ is at the
>   center of the cube while point $b$ is far from it.
>
> Calculate the following:  $$ E_{y}(a),E_{y}(b),B_{z}(a),B_{z}(b) $$ 
>   and  $$ E'_{y}(a),E'_{y}(b),B'_{z}(a),B'_{z}(b) $$ as they are seen in
>   a frame of reference moving at a speed $c\beta\hat{x}$.

**My efforts:**

I wrote that 
$$
E_{y}(a)=E_{y}(b)=E_{y}=E
$$

because the electric field is constant (in the lab frame).

Similarly, I wrote that 
$$
B_{y}(a)=B_{y}(b)=B_{z}=B
$$

because the magnetic field is constant (in the lab frame).

Then I used field transformation 
$$
E'_{\perp}=\gamma(E_{\perp}+\beta\times B)
$$
$$
B'_{\perp}=\gamma(B_{\perp}+-\beta\times E)
$$

to calculate the other four values requested.

I then looked at the solution, the solution claims that 
$$
E_{y}(a)=0,\, E_{y}(b)=E
$$

$$
B_{z}(a)=\beta E,\, B_{z}(b)=\beta E
$$

and the other field were calculated using the above transformations.

I then remembered that in a conductor the electric field is $0$,
this explains why $E_{y}(a)=0$.

I don't understand this situation completely, Please help me understand it by answering the following questions (that goes a bit beyond the question, but I find interesting and am having difficulties answering myself):

> 1) Why does $b$ have to be far from the conductor so we can say that
>   the electric is $E$ there ? what happens near the conductor ? (I
>   wonder if we can say something about the charge distribution on it
>   boundary, $\sigma$)
>
> 2) Why does the magnetic field does not change in space, inside or
>   outside the conductor ? (I know that the electric field does change,
>   at least inside the conductor, why shouldn't the magnetic field change
>   as well ?)
>
> 3) What can we say about the work done while moving the conductor in
>   the lab ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) the idea is to distinguish a point inside the conductor from a point outside it.

2) the magnetic field does not change inside a conductor because there are no moving electric charges to make such a change--since E field in the conductor is 0. caveat: if the conductor is ferromagnetic the magnetic field will not be the same inside and outside the metal.

3) if the direction of movement is not parallel to the B field then there will be an opposing magnetic force induced (Lorentz force). overcoming this force over a distance represents work done in the presence of a B field on top of the work already required to move the mass normally.